# Swift generics and enums and boxing

Tags: generics, swift

Sorry for the title... wasn't sure what to name it.

```
typealias JSON = AnyObject
typealias JSONArray = Array<AnyObject>

protocol JSONDecodable {
    class func decode(json: JSON) -> Self?
}

final class Box<T> {
    let value: T

    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

enum Result<A> {

    case Success(Box<A>)
    case Error(NSError)

    init(_ error: NSError?, _ value: A) {
        if let err = error {
            self = .Error(err)
        } else {
            self = .Success(Box(value))
        }
    }
}

func decode<T: JSONDecodable>(jsonArray: JSONArray?) -> Result<[T: JSONDecodable]> {
    if let jsonArray = jsonArray {
        var resultArray = [JSONDecodable]()
        for json: JSON in jsonArray {
            let decodedObject: JSONDecodable? = T.decode(json)
            if let decodedObject = decodedObject {
                resultArray.append(decodedObject)
            } else {
                return Result.Error(NSError()) //excuse this for now
            }
        }
        return Result.Success(Box(resultArray)) // THE ERROR IS HERE !!!!
    } else {
        return Result.Error(NSError()) //excuse this for now
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Cannot convert the expression's type 'Box' to type '[T: JSONDecodable]'

Could someone please explain why I can't do this, and how I can resolve it.

Thanks

Comment: the title of your question scared me: I thought you were looking to fight :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring the function as returning `Result<[T: JSONDecodable]>`, where the generic type is `[T: JSONDecodable]`, i.e. a dictionary.

Here:

```
return Result.Success(Box(resultArray)) // THE ERROR IS HERE !!!!
```

you are providing `Box<Array>` to `Result.Success`, but as per function declaration, it expects a `Box<Dictionary>`.

I don't know if the error is in the function declaration or in the `resultArray` type, btw the quickest fix I found is to change the function declaration:

```
func decode<T: JSONDecodable>(jsonArray: JSONArray?) -> Result<[JSONDecodable]>
```

to return `Result<[JSONDecodable]>` instead of `Result<[T: JSONDecodable]>`.

Comment: LOL ...! Cant believe it's the same error as my last question! Maybe I need another coffee... and I need to start paying you. Thanks again.

Comment: LOL I realize now it's the same mistake, I thought it was a real dictionary this time ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to my method that failed:

```
func decode<T: JSONDecodable>(jsonArray: JSONArray?) -> Result<[T]> {
  if let jsonArray = jsonArray {
    var resultArray = [T]()
    for json: JSON in jsonArray {
        let decodedObject: T? = T.decode(json)
        if let decodedObject = decodedObject {
            resultArray.append(decodedObject)
        } else {
            return Result.Error(NSError()) //excuse this for now
        }
    }
    return Result.Success(Box(resultArray))
  } else {
    return Result.Error(NSError()) //excuse this for now
  }
}
```